# Storyboard Adaptativo (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tenho uma animação no meu projeto WPF e queria saber se tem como o Storyboard ser responsivo.

Como nas configurações de Margin e Height/Width são responsivas marcando a opção auto queria saber se tem como fazer esse estilo auto na animação Storyboard também.

Exemplo:

Tenho uma grid que está a 20px a esquerda e a animação faz ela se mover até 0px a esquerda, mas tem outra animação que faz ela ir de 0px a esquerda à 50px a esquerda.

Tipo oque aconteceria normalmente é a animação iria começar setando a posição da grid à 0px a esquerda e ai sim iria ir a 50px a esquerda.

Tem como fazer essa animação ao invés de setar 0px depois mover a 50px pegar sua posição atual e mover a 50px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz a storyboard e seta o primeiro keyframe sem mudar nada ele pega as características atuais do objeto logo ele identifica e adapta a animação para o keyframe que você quer.